# How to center NeutralinoJS screen

Tags: centering, dimension, neutralinojs

Using [NeutralinoJS](https://neutralino.js.org/), how can start the app right in the center of the screen?

It should look like the splashscreen of any app. Unlike ElectronJS, [Neutralino's window options](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/window) doesn't seem to have a `center()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a simple javascript function by using native `API` of **neutralionJS**. Used `Neutralino.computer.getDisplays()` to height & width of the screen along with `Neutralino.window.getSize()` to height & width of the window and `Neutralino.window.move(x,y)` to center it. Note: x,y is the coordinates of the top right corner of the window. For a better explaination I have also attested a img demostrating it.

```js
async function centerWindow(){
    
    let display  = await Neutralino.computer.getDisplays();
    const displayHeight = display[0].resolution.height;
    const displayWidth = display[0].resolution.width;

    let window = await Neutralino.window.getSize();
    const windowHeight = window.height;
    const windowWidth = window.width;

    const x = (displayWidth - windowWidth) / 2;
    const y = (displayHeight - windowHeight) / 2;

    Neutralino.window.move(x,y);

}

centerWindow();
```

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHSLG.png)

The black dot is actual center of screen, red dot is where `Neutralino.window.move(x,y)` takes you too.